# Horizontal navigation not inline

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to keep the ul navigation in horizontal when clicking the first all the menu sets to horizontal but when clicking second, third or more, they change to vertical. I think its probably because of div's showing block and div content is on the same page. Any advice would certainly help me understand what i am doing wrong.

```
<ul class="taby">
  <li>
    <a name="form_a_1" 
       href="#div_&lt;?php echo 1;?&gt;" 
       id="form_a_1" 
       value="1" 
       onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_1&quot;);"
    >
      Who
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="div_1" 
     class="section2" 
     style="display:block;margin-top:40px;"
>
  CONTENT
</div>
<ul class="taby">
  <li>
    <a name="form_a_2" 
       href="#div_&lt;?php echo 2;?&gt;" 
       id="form_a_2" 
       value="1" 
       onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_2&quot;);"
    >
      Contact
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="div_2" 
     class="section2" 
     style="display:block;margin-top:40px;"
>
  CONTENT
</div>
```

This is the css below to style the html:

```
.taby{
    margin-left:0;
}
.taby > li > a{
    padding: 8px 12px 9px 12px;
    border-left: medium none transparent;
    border-bottom: medium none transparent;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #010E6F;
}
ul.taby > li{
    list-style: none;
} 
ul.taby > li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 3em;
}
.taby > li > a:hover {
    background:#428bca;
    color:black;
}
.taby > li + li {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.taby > li.active > a,
.taby > li.active > a:hover,
.taby > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you are trying to make buttons inline and make the submenu working.
There are plenty of css formatting problems and that would be better to avoid inline css rules in html file.

Please check the updated example:

```css
.taby {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.taby > li > a {
  padding: 8px 12px 9px 12px;
  border-left: medium none transparent;
  border-bottom: medium none transparent;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #010E6F;
}
ul.taby > li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  line-height: 3em;
}
.taby > li > a:hover {
  background: #428bca;
  color: black;
}
.taby > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.taby > li.active > a,
.taby > li.active > a:hover,
.taby > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: gray;
}
.taby li div {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.taby li:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="taby">
  <li><a name="form_a_1" href="#div_&lt;?php echo 1;?&gt;" id="form_a_1" value="1" onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_1&quot;);">Who</a>
    <div id="div_1" class="section2">CONTENT</div>
  </li>
  <li><a name="form_a_2" href="#div_&lt;?php echo 2;?&gt;" id="form_a_2" value="1" onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_2&quot;);">Contact</a>
    <div id="div_2" class="section2">CONTENT</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My example isn't what you want to create?

Comment: Using your example could not prevent horizontal menu from collapsing. yet i would accept your answer as its logical.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot how you want the final result be?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't understand your question properly. I think you probably need to align those 'header-content' sections horizontally, If this is what you really want you can accomplish it by this code.

```css
div.section {
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-left: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <ul class="taby">
    <li><a name="form_a_1" href="#div_&lt;?php echo 1;?&gt;" id="form_a_1" value="1" onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_1&quot;);">Who</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="div_1" class="section2" style="display:block;margin-top:40px;">CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <ul class="taby">
    <li><a name="form_a_2" href="#div_&lt;?php echo 2;?&gt;" id="form_a_2" value="1" onclick="return divclick(this,&quot;div_2&quot;);">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="div_2" class="section2" style="display:block;margin-top:40px;">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is menu are not in line at once, one menu at one time on clicking on the top is all what i am trying to explain, i mean menu's are changing their position top to bottom and vice-versa